# React.js, How to change one property of a object inside of map while keeping other property same?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects. Each object has two properties: value, faceup. The array is used as a state. I want to change the faceup property without effecting the value property. But, the code I wrote (handleclick) overwrites the value property of card object too. How to prevent this happen?

```
const Board = (props) =>{
 const [cards, setCards]= useState(createCards(props.cardnums));
 const handleclick = ()=>{
   setCards((preCards)=>preCards.map((card)=> ( card.value===1? card.faceup=true : card.faceup=false) ))
 }
function createCards(nums){ 
     var cardlist=[];
     for (var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
          var card = {value:nums[i], faceup:false };
          cardlist.push(card)
     }
     return cardlist
   }

 return(
   <div>   board {JSON.stringify(cards)} 
   <button onClick = {handleclick}>test</button>
   <div className= "gridContainer">
      {cards.map((card)=> (<div className="gridItem"> {card.value}</div>) )}
   </div>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [object spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (three dots - `...`) to do this for you:

```
const handleclick = () => setCards(preCards => preCards.map(
    card => ({
        ...card,
        faceup: card.value === 1
    });
));
```

This basically says, "copy all the previous values from `card`, then overwrite the `faceup` value.

Answer (score 0):

In the callback function inside the `map` function, you are not returning a card object, instead you are returning the return value of the expression `card.faceup=true` or `card.faceup=true`

you can change your `handleclick` function to fix this

```
  const handleclick = () => {
    setCards((preCards) =>
      preCards.map((card) => {
        return {
          ...card,
          faceup: card.value === 1
        };
      })
    );
  };
```

Here is codesandbox for it: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-wing-y9ru7